# How to verify web responses when using Spring and test-mvc

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-test-mvc

A question about how to use test-mvc for unit testing.

I have a simple controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {        
    private UserService business;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService bus)
    {
        business = bus;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUserById(@PathVariable String id) throws ItemNotFoundException{

        return business.GetUserById(id);

    }
```

(( My idea is to keep the controllers so thin as possible.))

To test this controller I am trying to do something like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
public class UserControllerTest extends ControllerTestBase {

UserService mockedService;

@Before
public void Setup()
{

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );   
    mockedService = mock(UserService.class);

}

@Test
public void ReturnUserById() throws Exception{

    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Lasse");

    stub(mockedService.GetUserById("lasse")).toReturn(user);

    MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new UserController(mockedService)).build()
    .perform(get("/users/lasse"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(?????????????????????????????);

}
```

My intention is to check that proper json code is returned,,,,,,

I am not a pro,,, so I have not found a way to replace ??????????????????????? with code to do verify the returned string but I am certain that there must be a elegant way to do this

Can anyone fill me in?

//lg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
content().string(containsString("some part of the string"))
```

assuming that you have this import:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.server.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

Update: Adding jsonPath also based on your comments:

You can add a dependency to [json-path](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/), the 1.0.M1 seems to depend on an much older version of json-path though:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

With this your test can look like this:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.persons[0].first").value("firstName"));
```

Comment: Ok, tanks. There are something called jsonPath I've tried to use. No luck however,, maby I was completly on the wrong way?

Comment: Thanks again,, this is so elegant it can get I suppose :)

Comment: Why should life be easy.
I am getting the following exception "java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"

How do I solve this?? (not to familar with Maven.

Comment: You can try this:`<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
   <version>4.10</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
   <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: I followed and I got: The method equalsTo(String) is undefined for the type JsonPathResultMatchers